# Trigger Chrome extension update checking

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, updates

I'm making a chrome extension ans I need updates to be installed as quick as they are published. In my own expriences, Chrome can take some very long time to autoupdate extension. What I want to do is to trigger from my extension the uptade checking when my Web Server says that a nex version hav been released.

I have search for this for 4 days and I haven't find every thing except a manual button in Chrome's Extension Tab...

Any idea ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible unfortunately.

Comment: @Brian That was what I feared